# How can I authorize the Cypress test for Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a problem authorizing the Cypress test for Sharepoint. If I enter the address into the browser in this format `http: // username: password @ localhost: port`, the required page will open without any problems.

But if I put it into the test and run Cypress, I'll get back the code **401: Unauthorized** right away. Do you have any help? Thank you.

Comment: Check out Elio Struyf's solution: https://www.eliostruyf.com/cypress-testing-sharepoint-solutions/ . I haven't had to implement something like this myself, but it looks to be solving the exact issue you're running into.

Comment: ok, thank you. I will read it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why have I problem with Cypress authorization to SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70260468/why-have-i-problem-with-cypress-authorization-to-sharepoint)